# Foo Bar Challenge Test Case Failing

Tags: java, arrays, subset

Right now in doing the Foo Bar Challenge and I'm close to getting to level 3. The only thing stopping me is a single case fail that I cannot determine. Can someone see why this code would fail?

Desired Result: If I Had an Array say int[] x = {1,4,1}; The program is supposed to get the subsets of this array, and find the subsets whose sum is the greatest multiple of 3, and return the subset in the greatest integer combination.

What's Happening?: Google Foo.Bar is giving me

> Test 1 passed!
>   Test 2 passed!
>   Test 3 passed!
>   Test 4 passed!
>   Test 5 failed.

**I'm wondering What case is causing this code to fail.**

Here' the purpose:

> You have L, a list containing some digits (0 to 9). Write a function answer(L) which finds the largest number that can be made from some or all of these digits and is divisible by 3. If it is not possible to make such a number, return 0 as the answer. L will contain anywhere from 1 to 9 digits.  The same digit may appear multiple times in the list, but each element in the list may only be used once.

Here's is my code which is probably verbose and can be done in a much simpler way:

```
public class Answer {   

public static int answer(int[] l) { 
    int n = l.length;
    int sum = 0;
    int max =0;
    int fragment = 0;

    // Run a loop to get all subsets of an Array
    for (int i = (1<<n)-1; i > 0; i--)
    {

        // Current subset
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)

            // (1<<j) is a number with jth bit 1
            // so when we 'and' them with the
            // subset number we get which numbers
            // are present in the subset and which
            // are not

            if ((i & (1 << j)) > 0) {
                sum+=l[j]; //Add the numbers of the subset together

                fragment = 10*fragment + l[j]; //Get the numbers used to get the sum
            }

        //Taking Advantage of the divisible rules of 3, if the sum of a subset is a multiple of 3 
        if(sum%3 == 0) {
            //Update the max multiple
            if (max<fragment) {
                max = fragment;
            }
        }

        sum=0;
        fragment = 0;

    }
    //Rearrange the max number order.
    return getLargestNumber(max);
}

//Function to reaarange an integer to it's greatest combination
private static int getLargestNumber(int input) {
    int[] numbers = new int[10];
    for(int i = input; i != 0; i /= 10) {
        numbers[i % 10]++;
    }
    int counter = 0;
    long result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; counter += numbers[i++]) {
        result += (int)((Math.pow(10, numbers[i]) * i - 1) / 9)
                    * Math.pow(10, counter);
    }
    return (int)result;
}

}
```

Edit: When I sort the Array using Arrays.sort, I pass Test 5, but now fail Test 3. Maybe Test has something to do with the arrangement of the array?

Comment: Have you tried with the simplest "algorithm", i.e., you  order the list, sum all the members of the list, then you pop everytime the smallest element until you reach 0 or a number divisible by 3?

Comment: @asettouf I dont think I exactly understading what you mean. As if I say had int  j[ ] = {4,3,5,1}, order it to {5,4,3,1} and keep pop out say 1 if i reach 0 or the sum equals a number divisble by 3?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think your code works... can you give an input where it fails?

Comment: @YossiVainshtein That's the issue, I can't find any. The only thing I can think of is that the variable fragment goes far beyond the int limit, causing max in turn to output a negative number. Such a case is int[] l = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

Comment: The biggest element will obviously be the sum of the elements in the list, then you just need to subtract the smallest element of the list see if you have a divisible by 3 element and so on

Comment: Doesn't it tell you why the test cases are failing? Most, if not all, sites I've used say either "wrong answer", "time limit exceeded" or whatever error message you got (or equivalent). Looping over all possible subsets will take exponential time, which would presumably be too slow for `n` above 20-something (if that much). What are the constraints on array size? Division by 3 has a special rule which indirectly leads to a somewhat simple (linear-time) solution to this problem.

Comment: @asettouf The problem isn't about summing the elements, it's about concatenating them (even if those are related). For either it needs to be a bit more complex than just repeatedly removing the smallest element - if you do that for `{6,4,3,1}`, you'll end up with `6` instead of `63` (or `6` instead of `9` if you're summing).

Comment: @Dukeling According to the question "L will contain anywhere from 1 to 9 digits. The same digit may appear multiple times in the list, but each element in the list may only be used once."

Comment: @JevonÇøö have you found the solution to this yet?